# Put variable in UserForm name

Tags: vba, variables, userform

I have following code in a subfunction:

```
If Auswertung.Controls("T" & Te & "F" & Fr & "Option1").Value = False Then
    falseSelection = falseSelection + 1
end If

If Auswertung2.Controls("T" & Te & "F" & Fr & "Option1").Value = False Then
    falseSelection = falseSelection + 1
end If
```

There are 15 UserForms, so I need to use a variable for the UserForm name.

```
"Auswertung" & X & .Controls("T" & Te & "F" & Fr & "Option1").Value
(This is wrong, but I do not know which capabilites VBA has)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Access VBA**

This is how you loop through all the forms of a project.  In your case you can modify it to be stored in a variable and then run a check on `.Name` to see if it matches the form you need

```
Dim f
For Each f In CurrentProject.AllForms
    Debug.Print f.Name
Next
```

OR you can simply refer to a form by its name in the following way

```
Forms.Item("Auswertung" & X).Controls
```

**Excel VBA**

```
Dim f As Object
For Each f In VBA.UserForms
    Debug.Print f.Name
Next
```

Comment: The second method with Forms.Item gives out a run-time error 424: Object required. What can I do?

Comment: When I type forms it doesn't get a capital letter, an indicator for a given object in VBA.

Comment: Is this in access or excel?

Comment: I have Excel. I took your example with "Dim f as Object". But I don't know what to do after "Debug.Print f.Name". I thought I must write following line after that: "f.Name.Controls("T" & Te & "F" & Fr & "Option1").Value" but it didn't work. I think it must have something to do with Debug.Print, instead I must use a different code?

Comment: If I declare f.Name as Variable (string) like this: "Dim StringN as String" and then "f.Name = StringN" and then "StringN.Controls..." it says "Compile Error: Invalid Qualifier".

Comment: `Debug.Print` is simply something to print to the intermediate window (`Control+G` to open/close it).  Before you refer to the controls you would basically do `if f.Name Like "Auswertung" then` to determine if that object is the form you want.  Then to refer to controls on the form you would say `f.Controls("myControlName")`.

Comment: F is the variable, as an Userform Object type. `f.name` is one of its many properties, being its name, as a string (`f.tag` , `f.controltiptext`, `f.caption` are other properties of f and also strings)

Comment: for example if `f` has a control named `label1`, you can refer to it as `f.label1`, or `f.controls("label1")`.  If you want to refer to a SUB or FUNCTION of the userform code that f points to, you can use `f.SubName` , but the sub or function must be a `Public`.